# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code

I was trying to access a SAP endpoint in my apex code when I got this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Any idea of how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to this Java security package bug

> http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044060

Anyway, I was able to resolve this error message by updating to the latest OpenJDK7